# Correct way to get the Facebook Authentication Token with Firebase after Redirection

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase and logging in with Facebook. I would like to use the Facebook Authentication token that Firebase returns me to make some calls to the Graph API, but the only Firebase method I found in the documentation is `getRedirectResult()`.

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
  if (result.credential) {
    // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // ...
  }
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
})
```

Is there another Firebase method I can call after I have been redirected? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not provide an API for that. You have to make the extra API call to Facebook to get that data using the Facebook Access Token (make sure the desired scopes were prompted when getting that access token).

```
AJAX GET 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + result.credential.accessToken
```